# Does $f(x,y)= x^2 + y^3 -3y - 2$ have a minimum at the point $(0,1)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let's consider the function:
$$f(x,y)= x^2 + y^3 -3y - 2.$$

I find two critical points:
$(0,1)$ and $(0,-1) $.
Using the definition method with
$h_1=x$ and $h_2=y-1$ to test the point $ (0,1) $, I find that:
$$f(h_1,1+h_2)-f(0,1)= h_1^2 + h_2^2(h_2+3).$$
We can use $h_1=0$ to find that the sign is not constant
so there is no extremum, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

$0<f_{xx}(0,1) = 2, f_{yy}(0,1) = 6, f_{xy}(0,1) = 0\implies D = f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2 = 2\cdot 6 - 0^2 = 12 > 0$. Thus $(0,1)$ is a local minimum for $f$, but it is **not** a global minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Your $$f(h_1,1+h_2)-f(0,1)=h_1^2+h_2^2(h_2+3)$$ is $≥0$ for every $(h_1,h_2)$ in $\Bbb R\times[-3,\infty)$, which is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$. So, you proved that $f$ has a local minimum at $(0,1)$. Your last sentence shows that this minimum is not global.

An analogous study at $(0,−1)$ results in $h_1^2+h_2^2(h_2-3)$, which takes both positive and negative values on any neighborhood of $(0,0)$, hence $f$ has a saddle point at $(0,−1)$.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct. Actually, $f$ has a local minimum at $(0,1)$. Note that\begin{align}f(x,y)-f(0,1)&=x^2+y^3-3y+2\\&=x^2+(y-1)^2(y+2),\end{align}which is always non-negative near $(0,1)$, and which, around $(0,1)$, is $0$ only at the point $(0,1)$ itself.

Comment: So the minimum is local not global?

Comment: Indeed. Clearly, $f(0,-3)=-20<-4=f(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative test can be used here as well. The hessian matrix of second derivatives is
$$
    Hf(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 6y \end{pmatrix}
$$
We see that at the critical point $(0,1)$, the matrix is diagonal with two positive entries. This tells us $(0,1)$ is a local minimum. At the other critical point $(0,-1)$, the matrix has negative determinant, so the critical point is a saddle point.

There is neither a global maximum or minimum value, since $\lim_{y\to \infty} f(0,y) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{y\to-\infty} f(0,y) = - \infty$.